# Retrieving values from hashmap and sending to new activity

Tags: android, hashmap, google-maps-markers

I am new to programming so, please try to explain in simple language. I have a map with markers and I have used a `HashMap` to store numbers related to the markers.

```
HashMap<Marker,String> hash= new HashMap<Marker, String>();
```

In my `HashMap`, I have used the markers as keys and the numbers as values. I would like the number of a specific marker to be sent to a new activity when the marker is clicked. How can I do this and may I get a sample code for this?

Answer (score 1):

first get the number from hashmap using specific marker like this

```
String number = hash.get(marker);
```

thenyou could send data to other activity like this

> OtherActivity is name of activity class where u want to send the data

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("data", number);
startActivity(intent)
```

at other activity onCreateMethod() use this to retrive data

```
String number = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
```

Comment: Am sorry but I don't know how to do that

Comment: There is right click sign(tick) on my answer, just click there n it will become accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**This can help you:**

```
 @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
           String number = hash.get(marker);
           Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, NumberActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("NUMBER", number);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: I have tried your sample code but unfortunately its not working.I get no errors but the new activity is not opened

Comment: googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
      
      @Override
      public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       HashMap<Marker, String> hash = new HashMap<Marker, String>();
                   String number = hash.get(marker);
                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DailyMenu.class);
                   intent.putExtra("Number",number);
                   
       return false;
      }
     });

Comment: That's what i have used

Comment: Where is 'startActivity(intent)' ?